# Perl: Split IP address into hostid and netid

Tags: perl, networking, ip, subnet, netmask

Simple enough, I'd like to split a given IP address into netid (as defined by the netmask) and the hostid in Perl. Example:

```
    $network = NetAddr::IP->new('192.168.255.255/29') || die "invalid space $_";
```

Now `$network->mask` returns `255.255.255.248`. But there're no methods in [NetAddr::IP](http://search.cpan.org/~miker/NetAddr-IP-4.075/IP.pm) to apply the mask to split the address into its netid and hostid portions in the `/29` space.

[NetAddr::IP::Util](http://search.cpan.org/~miker/NetAddr-IP-4.075/Lite/Util/Util.pm) mentions the operators to do so, but it's documentation is a mess.

At least the netid can be extracted using [Net::NetMask](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Net-Netmask-1.9019/lib/Net/Netmask.pod):

```
    $netid = Net::Netmask->new('192.168.255.255/29')->base;
```

This yields `192.168.255.248`. Again, no method to get the host portion `0.0.0.7`. Maybe the best would be to pack/unpack the IPs into 32 bit int and then simply `&` them out. Then it would be easier to print the binary representations of IP addresses too, which I found can be really helpful for debugging and documentation purposes.

Comment: Why would you want `0.0.0.7`? Sounds like an XY problem

Comment: It is not. The method to extract the hostid is simply missing, and might be available somewhere else in Perl. `NetAddr::IP::Util` looks promising but no idea how to use it for the purpose.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: ...because for 192.168.255.255/29 the net id (aka subnet mask) is 255.255.255.248 and the host id 0.0.0.7. For 127.0.0.1/8 the net id is 255.0.0.0 and the host id 0.0.0.1. In other words, the hostid is the remainder of the IP address when the subnet mask was applied. How to get it in Perl?

Comment: I know *what* you want. I asked *why*.

Comment: [Subnetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork). Divide the host id further. Embedded system where multiple devices are inter-connected and the central device would use a subnet per connection. The wires are optical fibers which are resistant against radiation. The actual implementation is in C++. Wrote some Perl scripts to test things out.

Comment: Yes. It was only an example when I wrote the post.

Comment: I'm not asking about `0.0.0.7` specifically. So let me rephrase:

Comment: huh? What you call "hostid" is useless for subnetting. The size of the existing subnet would be useful so you know what you have. Divide that (using `>>`) to get a new subnet size. Simple addition will find the new starts

Comment: Actually you can do with IP addresses what you want. On our devices we could have masks with "holes" in them as well, like 255.255.255.3. AFAIK this is even covered by [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1219). But I think we shouldn't discuss that here.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. If you have subnets of that sort, it comes down to allocating bits of the mask. To find how many bits you have to play with, you use substract the size of the mask from 32.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hostmask() method

```
$host_wildcard = Net::Netmask->new('192.168.255.255/29')->hostmask;
```

Comment: I don't think so. `hostmask` returns the mask, not the value. In my example they happen to be the same (0.0.0.7), however, in case of 192.168.255.254 etc. not. Maybe my example IP was a bit misleading. Sorry for that.